# StasD collects data but is not displayed on Graphite web UI

Tags: playframework, graphite, statsd

my statsd.conf:

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003,
  graphiteHost: "graphite.bluemailapp.com",
  port: 8125,
  debug: true,
  dumpMessages: true,
  keyFlush: {
    interval: "10000",
    log: "/opt/statsd/statsd.log"
  }
}
```

I see in my statsd log the counters I want to see but they are not in the graphite ui. what could I be missing?

.. only new metrics are missing.
directories are not being created.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Try to send a metric to Graphite directly first to identify the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possible issues:

1. Is the port 2003 open on the graphite host? Check firewalls.
2. Does whisper have write permissions on the data directory? Check logs.
3. Does graphite-web have read permissions on the data directory?